# Why doesn't my subscription on a WatchQuery fire when the same data set is returned?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to invoke a callback after I execute a refetch against a watchQuery.

When I call refetch if the data returned is the same then my subscription callback doesn't get fired, however this works fine when the data is different.

My assumption is it's related to caching but changing the cache policy doesn't help.

What can I do to execute some code after the refetch even if the data remains the same?

Current implementation: I am using the React Apollo Client to create a WatchQuery like this:

```
apolloClient.watchQuery({ query, variables, errorPolicy: 'all' });
```

Subscribing to the query works correctly when I call refetch later on as long as the data returned is different from the current result:

```
query.subscribe(console.log);

// later I call refetch with new vars, a search term in this case

query.refetch(newVariables);
```

If the data set returned from the query is identical (due to the same search outcome for example) then the subscribe method doesn't get called.

Changing the `fetchPolicy` for the query doesn't seem to have any positive impact.

What should I try next? How can I invoke something after a refetch even if the data returned is the same?

***Package versions:***

*(I did try an upgrade in hopes there was a bug fix but it had no impact)*

```
"apollo-client": "^2.5.1",
"react-apollo": "^2.5.5",
```

Comment: I imagine this may be intended behavior. It's been a while since I've looked at the client source code, but I'm pretty sure the subscription is to the relevant cache values themselves. This means any updates to the cache will trigger changes, regardless of origin (network vs. direct changes to the cache), but it also means if the cache values stay the same, there's no need to notify listeners.

Comment: If the cache value stays the same, there's no need to rerender. Why exactly do you need the listener to be triggered?

Comment: Prior to refetch I start a 'loading modal' and stop it in the subscription method, without it firing it sticks around. @DanielRearden

Comment: Refetch [returns a Promise](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ObservableQuery.refetch) so you could just await it and then close the modal, right?